# I'd like to use a wildcard with the SET command in Windows Batch so I don't have to know exactly what is in the string in order to match it

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I'd like to use a wildcard with the SET command in Windows Batch so I don't have to know exactly what is in the string in order to match it.

Is this possible?

If this has already been asked and answered I apologize, I searched for a good while, but could not find it.

Comment: A sample would be nice, do you want find a regualar expression or what kind of wildcards do you want to use

Comment: +1 Answering your own question definitely shows research effort ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A: Yes. But it is not as powerful as it should be.

But first, let's answer a question that you didn't ask (yet) because it is a natural follow-up question.

Q: Will the question mark match any single character in the batch string search and replace with SET?
   A: No. It is a regular character, and will only match it'self.

The asterisk **IS** a wildcard and WILL match multiple characters, but will **ONLY** match everything from the **very beginning of the string**. Not in the middle, and not from the end.

Useful Searches:

```
*x  
*how are you?
```

The above two searches CAN be matched. The first will match everything up to and including the first "x
" it runs across. The second one will match everything up to and including the first "how are you?" it finds.

Legal, but Unuseful, searches:

```
x*
Hello*
One*Three
```

The above three searches can NEVER be matched. Oddly they are also legal, and will cause no errors.
One exception: Hello* and x* WILL match themselves, but only if they are the very beginning of the string. (Thanks Jeb!)

Two examples you can type or paste in at a command prompt:

> REM A successful search and replace.
>   SET X=Hello my friend. How are you?
>   SET X=%X:*.=%
>   ECHO Output: "%X%"
>
> Output: " How are you?"
>
> REM Unexpected action causing an unsuccessful search and replace.
>   SET X=Hello my friend. How are you?
>   SET X=%X:.*=%
>   ECHO Output: "%X%"
>
> Output: "Hello my friend. How are you?"

Logiclly, .* should match everthing from the period on, resulting in the string
being truncated to "Hello my friend". But since the * only matches from the start
of the string, the .* matches nothing, and so the string was left unchanged.

Comment: `Hello*` can match a string, the asterix is a normal character if it's not the first. `set var=Hello*world` `set var=%var:Hello*=%` will result to `world`

Comment: Oops! Didn't think about that!

Answer (score 0):

## Extremely old, but useful

#### As an executable [`set-ast`](https://gist.github.com/Ephellon/8a942ea4bf271cf880dccc4eade49091)

```
set string=abc*def*ghi
set-ast string "-dash-"
  :: -> "abc-dash-def-dash-ghi"
```

Where the arguments are given as `set-ast <variable-name> <replacement-string>`

---

#### replace `*` with `-dash-` (one time only)

*Note: delayed expansion **must** be enabled*

```
set string=abc*def
  :: -> "abc*def"
set right=%string:**=%
  :: -> "def"
set left=!string:%right%=!
  :: -> "abc*"
set left=%left:~0,-1%
  :: -> "abc"

set new-string=%left%-dash-%right%
  :: -> "abc-dash-def"
```