# Replace character of string in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I need to replace character `*` from a string which is some what like this:
`*10.*31.**2.*65`

I want to remove all the `*` from this string using batch script.

Comment: Note: `*` is a special character, so you can't use the `%var:a=b%` syntax.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET mystring=*10.31.*2.*65
:deaster
FOR /f "tokens=1* delims=*" %%i IN ("%mystring%") DO (
   SET mystring=%%j
   IF DEFINED mystring (
      SET mystring=%%i%%j
      GOTO deaster
   ) ELSE (
      SET mystring=%%i
   )
)
ECHO result=%mystring%=
```

Answer (score 49):

You can simplify the removal process to one line. For example, if I had a string like this:

```
set string=hello!
```

and I wanted to remove the "!" in it, I can just do

```
set string=%string:!=%
```

The string will now have the value `"hello"` instead of `"hello!"`

**edit:** As [jeb pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441422/replace-character-of-string-in-batch-script/25812295#comment63141151_25812295), you can't replace `"*"` using this method. This is because `*` is a wildcard character for batch file pattern matching (brilliant explanation of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11685376/3704301)). I did not know this at the time of posting this answer as I assumed this replacement method worked for all input strings. If you specifically need to replace `*`, I'd recommend following [magoo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15441692/3704301). Otherwise, I will be keeping this answer up for those who need a general, short, one-liner solution to batch string replacements.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the qeustion, as you can't replace a `*` with this method. As replace expressions wirh a beginning `*` has a special meaning.

Comment: transform from 1.2.3.4 to 1,2,3,4    setlocal set string=1.2.3.4 set string=%string:.=,%

Comment: This uses syntax `%variable:StrToFind=NewStr%`, see https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html

Answer (score 4):

You don't need an entire script for this.  You just need a single `for /f` loop.

```
C:\Users\rojo>set test=*10.*31.**2.*65

C:\Users\rojo>echo %test%
*10.*31.**2.*65

C:\Users\rojo>for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=.^*" %I in ("%test%") do @set test=%I.%J.%K.%L

C:\Users\rojo>echo %test%
10.31.2.65
```

If you want to put the `for` loop into a batch script, use `%%I`, `%%J`, `%%K` and `%%L` instead of the single percents.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to the stated problem is to use a PowerShell *replace* command within your batch script.

```
set var=*10.*31.*2.*65
echo %var%>var.txt && powershell -command "(get-content var.txt) -replace '[\x2A]+', '' | set-content var.txt"
set /p var=<var.txt
echo %var%
```

In the above code, the second line

- writes your string into a text file
- calls a PowerShell command to get the contents of that file
- replaces the * character with null
- overwrites the text file with the new value

Once that is done, you read the value back into your variable.

To further explain the *replace* command, the first single quotes is what you are searching for.  We are using square brackets to identify the * character as a [hex character](http://www.asciitable.com/) (\x2A is the hex value for *).  After the comma, the second set of single quotes contains no value so that the searched object is removed.

Another option is to use a caret character to search for everything *except* for what is identified in the brackets. This would remove everything we other than want you want to keep. To do that you would replace the second line with:

```
echo %var%>var.txt && powershell -command "(get-content var.txt) -replace '[^\x30-x39\x2E]+', '' | set-content var.txt"
```

The first set of characters, \x-30-x39, identify 0 - 9.  The \x2E are periods.

Once you are done with the text file, enter a line to delete it.

```
if exist var.txt del var.txt
```

Comment: I've never seen the structure `command1 > file | command2`.  Does that do anything special?  Would `&&` be a better choice than `|`?

Comment: Thanks @mwfearnley.  You are correct.  The && is the right choice.  The && means to execute the second command once the first command succeeds.  The pipe sends the output of the first command to be used by the second.  I have updated the line to use &&.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "str=*10.*31.**2.*65"

set "char=" & set "repl=" & set "loc=0"

echo !str!

call :replace

echo !repl!

exit /b

:replace
  set "char=!str:~%loc%,1!
  if "!char!" == "" exit /b
  if "!char!" equ "*" set "char=_"
  set "repl=!repl!!char!"
  set /a "loc+=1"
goto :replace

endlocal
```

This is another solution. maybe a little slow, but call set is too slow.

Answer (score 1):

This code replaces the a to b character:

```
Set search=%search:a=b%
```

Comment: Even the first comment on the question shows this already and explains why it can't be used here for `*`

Answer (score -1):

Look into [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), the stream editor. If you are on Windows (assuming you are), you can find precompiled binaries on the web.

```
echo "*10.31.*2.*65" | sed 's/\*//g'
```