# Why does `set test=%test:*=.*%` not work, says `=.*% was unexpected at this time`?

Tags: batch-file, replace

I have a variable `test` with value `*string*`, I am trying to replace `*` with `.*` like this

```
set test=%test:*=.*%
```

but I get an error saying `=.*% was unexpected at this time.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is a wildcard in variable replacement when using at the start position, so you can't replace them like this

> ```bat
> ::Delete the character string 'ab' and everything before it
>    SET _test=12345abcabc
>    SET _result=%_test:*ab=% 
>    ECHO %_result%          =cabc
>
> ::Replace the character string 'ab' and everything before it with 'XY'
>    SET _test=12345abcabc
>    SET _result=%_test:*ab=XY% 
>    ECHO %_result%          =XYcabc
>
>    SET _test=The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
>
>    :: To delete everything after the string 'brown'  
>    :: first delete 'brown' and everything before it
>    SET _endbit=%_test:*brown=%
>    Echo We dont want: [%_endbit%]
> ```
>
> [How-To: Edit/Replace text within a Variable](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

For example with your string `*string*` it can be used to remove the left or right part like this

```bat
D:\>echo %test%
*string*

D:\>echo %test:*str=spr%
spring*

D:\>echo %test:*r=st%
sting*
```

To do a general replacement you should use [jrepl](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jrepl) which is a lot more versatile

[JREPL.BAT - regex text processor with support for text highlighting and alternate character sets](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044)

Possible alternatives:

- [I need to match or replace an asterisk * in a batch environmental variable using only native Windows commands. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11685375/995714)
- [Replace character of string in batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15441422/995714)

Comment: I have jrepl but how do I use for a variable?

Comment: @Bricktop `echo %test% | jrepl "\*" ".*"`

Comment: no I mean how do I record the change into new/same variable so I won't have to do this everywhere I use it?

Comment: @Bricktop use `for /f` [How to set commands output as a variable in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6359820/995714). Or read the other question, there are many other ways to do that