# Why is asterisk special in CMD character replacing syntax?

Tags: batch-file

Execute the following 3 statements and see the result.

```
set myvar=11?22*33

echo %myvar:?=_%

echo %myvar:*=_%
```

On Win7/10, The second one replaces a question mark with an underscore, great.

But the third one fails with `=_% was unexpected at this time.` So, I'd like to ask:

- What is the special meaning of `*` here?
- How to have batch statement replace `*` with underscore?

[image]

### ==== Update ====

Well, this has been asked by someone and got answers: [I need to match or replace an asterisk * in a batch environmental variable using only native Windows commands. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685375/)

Comment: The asterisk is a special character, a wildcard/glob, in your expansion command, and is not therefore seen as a literal character. Batch files are not designed for replacing characters in strings, and you should therefore use one of the other built in true scripting languages, _(for instance, VBScript / JScript / PowerShell)_.

Comment: Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `set /?` and read the output usage help. There is described: __"str1" can begin with an asterisk, in which case it will match everything from the beginning of the expanded output to the first occurrence of the remaining portion of str1.__ So the asterisk `*` has a special meaning on string substitutions on being found after `VariableName:` by `cmd.exe`

Comment: To replace the asterisk, you need to loop through the characters of the string, using [sub-string expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)…