# Using Wildcard in Set command in batch file

Tags: batch-file

ok I am trying to strip the first two characters from a file I am using this script.

```
@echo off
Set "InputFile=C:\New Folder\test.txt"
Set "OutputFile=C:\New Folder\New\test.txt"

setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion > "%OutputFile%"

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims= " %%a in ("%InputFile%") do (
set s=%%a
>> "%OutputFile%" echo.!s:~2!
)
```

which works perfect if I use the correct name. What I need to do is use a wild characters since the name of the file is different each time. When trying this it does not work.

```
@echo off
Set "InputFile=C:\New Folder\H*.txt"
Set "OutputFile=C:\New Folder\New\H*.txt"

setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion > "%OutputFile%"

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims= " %%a in ("%InputFile%") do (
set s=%%a
>> "%OutputFile%" echo.!s:~2!
)
```

Comment: this will remove the first two characters from every line in your file. Is this, what you want?

Answer (score 0):

from

[I'd like to use a wildcard with the SET command in Windows Batch so I don't have to know exactly what is in the string in order to match it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684073/id-like-to-use-a-wildcard-with-the-set-command-in-windows-batch-so-i-dont-have)

> The asterisk IS a wildcard and WILL match multiple characters, but
>   will ONLY match everything from the very beginning of the string. Not
>   in the middle, and not from the end.
>
> Useful Searches:
>
> *x
>   *how are you? The above two searches CAN be matched. The first will match everything up to and including the first "x " it runs across.
>   The second one will match everything up to and including the first
>   "how are you?" it finds.
>
> Legal, but Unuseful, searches:
>
> x* Hello* One*Three The above three searches can NEVER be matched.
>   Oddly they are also legal, and will cause no errors. One exception:
>   Hello* and x* WILL match themselves, but only if they are the very
>   beginning of the string. (Thanks Jeb!)

Answer (score 0):

the surrounding `for`-loop does the wildcard processing (giving full qualified filenames)

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('dir /b C:\New Folder\H*.*') do (
 echo processing %%i

  Set "InputFile=C:\New Folder\%%i"
  Set "OutputFile=C:\New Folder\New\%%i"

  setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion > "%OutputFile%"

  for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims= " %%a in ("%InputFile%") do (
    set s=%%a
    >> "%OutputFile%" echo.!s:~2!
  )
  endlocal
)
```

Note: if you have more than one line in those files, it will remove the first two characters **from each line***.